# How to navigate through fragments without adding it to the backstack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 3 `Fragments` **A**, **B** and **C**. When I press a button in fragment **A**, I have to navigate to fragment **B** (to initialize it) which should implicitly navigate to fragment **C**. Meanwhile, it should not be added to backstack, so that when I return back from fragment **C**, it should directly come back to fragment **A**. Can someone tell how to do this?

I have tried not adding it to the backstack, but it doesn't work out. It throws `NullPointerException` while coming back.

```
final int fragId = manager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG )
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: You'll need to add **fragment B**, but replace **fragment C**. In such case, `onBackPress()`, you'll come back to A.

Comment: Add disallowAddToBackStack() call before calling commitAllowingStateLoss()

Answer (score 0):

if you pass argument correctly to your fragment, when pop from backStack this bundle restore well!

```
 public class HomeProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    public static HomeProfileFragment newInstance(String name){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("ARG_NAME",name);
        HomeProfileFragment fragment = new HomeProfileFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String name = getArguments().getString("ARG_NAME");
    }
}
```

and just use replace for adding to backStack:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frag_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
```

and implement `onBackPressed()` :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```